# New to Ubuntu, got a few problems

Tags: drivers, ati, monitor

So I built myself a lovely new computer, and decided to give ubuntu a go. So far, I'm confused. A  quick google search left me with a headache. So here are my problems. Keep in mind that I'm completely new to ubuntu, so give very specific step by step instructions. First off, I can't see the edges of the screen. The side panel and top bar are not on screen, and it's not the resolution. It's like I'm zoomed in and can only stare at the center of the screen. Secondly, my motherboard drivers refuses to install. A google search tells me that I don't need to install drivers. Is this true? And third, how the hell do I install the graphics card drivers? These are my questions so far, and I'll bet I have more to come.

Comment: You don't usually need any motherboard, chipset, sound or network drivers. About desktop, it is possible that your graphics card drivers don't work correctly. What ubuntu version you downloaded? It's hard to install graphics drivers when your desktop does not work. Have you seen environment on live DVD?

Comment: ...and I don't know what you are talking about. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. What does "have you seen environment on live DVD" mean? anyways, I kinda figured out I don't need mobo drivers, as I'm online now without downloading anything.

Answer (score 0):

The only drivers you need to think about for the most time is the graphic drivers, they are found under *additional software* in system settings.

Start system settings from a terminal, open a terminal via **ctrl + alt + t**.

type this to start system settings:

```
unity-control-settings
```

Click on **additional software** and choose a graphic driver from there.

This will hopefully solve your screen issue. :)

Comment: command didn't work. But I just updated ubuntu and downloaded fglrx. The screen finally fits, but every few seconds my screen spazzes out. As in I get these horizontal lines of the same color. Kinda annoying. How do I fix that? My friend also has that problem, but he fixes it by going into crossfire mode as he has two gfx cards. I only have one. What do I do?

Comment: @Raytsou can you open system settings now when the screen works?

Comment: Yes. Everything's good and running now, besides the screen spazzing out. It's only a small portion, not the whole screen tho. It's like an elongated pixel. But everything else is fine, I even downloaded steam.